# Apache - Difference between ScriptAlias and WSGIScriptAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, configuration, wsgi, scriptalias

I'm using apache on RHEL Linux server
In my /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf there are two directives:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /apps /var/www/apps
<Directory /var/www/apps >
   Options MultiViews ExecCGI
   MultiviewsMatch Handlers
   SetHandler wsgi-script
   Order allow, deny
   allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /scripts /var/www/scripts
<Directory /var/www/scripts >
   Options MultiViews ExecCGI
   MultiviewsMatch Handlers
   SetHandler wsgi-script
   Order allow, deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

What is the difference?
I understand that WSGIScriptAlias is restricted for running Python scripts and ScriptAlias also allows running perl scripts.

Can I always use ScriptAlias instead of WSGIScriptAlias? Are there any performance advantages of using WSGIScriptAlias instead of ScriptAlias?

Answer (score 4):

ScriptAlias is for cgi-script handler in Apache. WSGIScriptAlias is equivalent for wsgi-script. If you want to mix them in the same directory, don't use either, use Alias, Options ExecCGI, AddHandler directives instead. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Answer (score 1):

`WSGIScriptAlias` is a parameter used for the `python` module and they can't be used interchangeably.